# Swift JSValue callWithArguments() within nested completion handler results in BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift

I have a simple function that takes a completion handler as a JSValue. It's a JSValue because I'm using this function as part of JSExport protocol.

This function then calls another internal method with another completion handler. When this second handler is called, I want to callWithArguments on the JSValue.

This all works as expected when I callWithArguments from outside the second completion handler, but I get a BAD_ACCESS when calling from the second handler.

```
func myFunction(completion: JSValue) {

    // If I put completion.callWithAttributes([]) here, everything works fine.

    self.mySecondFunction(completion: {(result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Void in

        // If I put completion.callWithAttributes([]) here, I get a BAD_ACCESS
    })
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to do the following

```
[self.callback.context[@"setTimeout"]  
             callWithArguments:@[callback, @0, items]];
```

when you are going to send response to the JavaScriptCore counterpart. This will prevent the TVML UI MainThread to hang. As you can see it's a call of the setTimeout javascript function with delay 0, your callback and items as parameters like:

```
setTimeout(callback,0,items)
```

I'm not sure how you are creating the alert anyways here is one from Apple:

```
createAlert : function(title, description) {  
  var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
  <document>  
  <alertTemplate>  
  <title>${title}</title>  
  <description>${description}</description>  
  <button class="btn_close">  
  <text>OK</text>  
  </button>  
  </alertTemplate>  
  </document>`  
  var parser = new DOMParser();  
  var alertDoc = parser.parseFromString(alertString, "application/xml");  
  return alertDoc  
  }
```

There is no direct relationship with the alert and the behavior you are seeing here, it's more a side effect of calling this

```
completion.callWithArguments([])
```

in a unexpected way. It's better that you save your completion somewhere, and get a reference to it on the object instance. Then, when the  long task ends, you call it. Also if you are performing a long task, it's reasonable that you move everything in a NSOperation like this:

```
/** JavaScriptCore Callback Operation */  
@interface JSCallbackOperation: NSOperation  
@property(nonatomic, strong) JSValue*callback;  
@property(nonatomic, strong) id items;  
@end  
@implementation JSCallbackOperation  
- (id)initWithItems:(id)items callback:(JSValue*)callback {  
    if(self = [super init]) {  
        self.items=items;  
        self.callback=callback;  
    }  
    return self;  
}  
- (void)main {  
    @autoreleasepool {  
        if(self.callback) {  
            NSLog(@"Dispatching %@", self.callback);  
            [self.callback.context[@"setTimeout"]  
             callWithArguments:@[self.callback, @0, self.items]];  
        }  
    }  
}
```

At this point you define a helper a call the callbacks with parameters then:

```
#pragma mark - API Helper  
- (void)handleResponseWithItems:(id)items callback:(JSValue*)callback {  

    NSArray *active_and_pending_operations = operationQueue.operations;  
    NSInteger count_of_operations = operationQueue.operationCount;  

    NSLog(@"Running operations: %ld of %ld", active_and_pending_operations.count, count_of_operations);  

    JSCallbackOperation *op = [[JSCallbackOperation alloc] initWithItems:items callback:callback];  
    [op setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal];  
    [op setCompletionBlock:^{  
        NSLog(@"Operation completed.");  
    }];  
    [operationQueue addOperation:op];  

}
```